# Getting my first TWI program working?

Tags: gpio

I am new with Raspberry and frankly didn't do programmation for 20 years.

I am learning Python pretty fast and also acquired the PI2 and the HTU21D-F

I was under the impression this was an easy first step !!!!

Can you share a code that works. IT would be my first run at an I2C TWI program and would probably help me a lot in getting other sensors working.

Appreciate your help. I promiss that when Im good, I will answer questions rather then asking for help. D.

Answer (score 3):

You need to start by enabling I2C.

Add the following line to /boot/config.txt

> dtparam=i2c1=on

Add the following line to /etc/modules

> i2c-dev

Download the i2c-tools package

> sudo apt-get install i2c-tools

Add your user (assumed to be pi) to the i2c group

> sudo adduser pi i2c

Power off

Connect your device to SDA (Pi pin 3), SCL (PI pin 5), ground (Pi pin 6) and 3V3 (Pi pin 1).

Power on

Your device should be visible on the I2C bus using i2cdetect

> i2cdetect -y 1

Comment: THANKS A LOT.  I can see the device sitting at 0x040. Now, How can I read the value within this address... I am trying to read the Humidity and the temperature value. Will I need to reproduce the I2C protocol with SLA W - ACK - W data - ACK   etc......

Comment: Personally I'd search on the www for Raspberry Pi plus HTU21D-F to see if you can find some I2C examples.  I'm sure it's trivial but without the device it's impossible to experiment.  You could try playing with the i2cset/i2cget commands from the command line.

Comment: Thank joan. Will try it later today. Appreciate your help.